Ошибка при запуске Docker: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine'
Осваиваю Docker, пытаюсь запустить проект.
При добавлении файла .htaccess получаю ошибку при запуске:

"/var/www/html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps
misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server
configuration", в браузере 500 ошибка.

Поиски решения подсказали, что может быть проблема с rewrite_module,  но у меня он есть и работает. Еще был предложен вариант в конфигурации apache прописать:
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

Но все это не помогло и при запуске контейнера в логах все та же ошибка.
Может кто то сталкивался с подобным или есть идеи как решить можно

все получилось. в конфигах ничего прописывать не нужно, нужно было нормально запустить rewrite_module, внутри контейнера, а не вне
потом появляется аналогичная ошибка, тоже из htaccess, только ругается не на RewriteEngine, а на Header. нужно аналогично включить модуль header, как и rewrite
